# Rock Paper Scissors Game (js) - How can to create a round function

Tags: javascript

**The problem**

- In the playRound function I am returning a function that should stop once the result object equals 5 which translates to 5 rounds. However, It only plays a game and then once you try to play again; it logs tie repeatedly.

**Here's what I tried**

I Used only my convertMoves() function instead of having both my playRound() function in the returning function

**Expected Results**

Once I answer the prompt, I want it not log tie but different outcomes that make sense. It should not always be 'tie', 'tie', 'tie' but rather 'win', 'tie', 'lose', 'win', 'tie'

```js
    var moves, result;

    moves = {
        rock: 0, 
        paper: 1, 
        scissors: 2,
    };

    result = {
        win: 0,
        tie: 0,
        lose: 0
    };

    function convertMoves() {
        playerSelection = prompt('Please choose rock, paper, or scissors').toLowerCase();
        return moves[playerSelection];
    }

    function computerPlay() {
        var movesValues = Object.values(moves);
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * movesValues.length);
        return movesValues[random];
    } 

    function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
        var processResult = (3 + computerSelection - playerSelection) % 3;

        if (!processResult) {
            ++result.tie;
            console.log('tie');
        } else if (1 == processResult) {
            ++result.lose;
            console.log('You lost');
        } else {
            ++result.win;
            console.log('You won');
        }

        return function() {
            var rounds = 0;
            var resultValues = Object.values(result);

            for (var i = 0; i < resultValues.length; i++) {
                rounds += resultValues[i];
            }

            console.log(rounds);
            if (rounds !== 5) {
                convertMoves();
                playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    var computerSelection = computerPlay();
    var playerSelection = convertMoves();

    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`playerSelection` just get `undefined` because its value is not updating after its set at once in the closure function. By doing this `playerSelection = convertMoves();` its working fined now. Hope this will solve your problem.

```js
var moves, result;

    moves = {
        rock: 0, 
        paper: 1, 
        scissors: 2,
    };

    result = {
        win: 0,
        tie: 0,
        lose: 0
    };

    function convertMoves() {
        playerSelection = prompt('Please choose rock, paper, or scissors').toLowerCase();
        return moves[playerSelection];
    }

    function computerPlay() {
        var movesValues = Object.values(moves);
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * movesValues.length);
        return movesValues[random];
    } 

    function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    debugger
        var processResult = (3 + computerSelection - playerSelection) % 3;

        if (!processResult) {
            ++result.tie;
            console.log('tie');
        } else if (1 == processResult) {
            ++result.lose;
            console.log('You lost');
        } else {
            ++result.win;
            console.log('You won');
        }

        return function() {
            var rounds = 0;
            var resultValues = Object.values(result);

            for (var i = 0; i < resultValues.length; i++) {
                rounds += resultValues[i];
            }

            console.log(rounds);
            if (rounds !== 5) {
                playerSelection = convertMoves();
                playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    var computerSelection = computerPlay();
    var playerSelection = convertMoves();

    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)());
```

Answer (score 1):

The issues with your code:

- You are calling computerPlay only once, and then using the same values for all the other rounds.
- You have two different playerSelection variables, one declared in the outermost scope, and the other is the argument of playRound.
- Before calling playRound you call convertMoves but you don’t use the return value, but you pass the same argument that the function had received.

Some tips:

- Avoid declaring variables in the global scope.
- Avoid setting the value of variables from the outer scope in a function, it is better to return the value and let the caller decide what to do with it.
- Try not to do too many things in the same function. playRound is computing the result of one round, but it is also returning a function that runs other 5 rounds. Maybe it would be better to have playRound playing just one round, and have a loop that call it 5 times?

Comment: Thank you, I was using the closure function to practice. I know I was doing too much in one function but really, thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

The way you've used recursion indirectly through a closure makes this kind of mind-bending -- especially since this isn't the kind of problem that would normally warrant the use of recursion.

The quick fix for your issue is to call the *choice* functions on each iteration.

I've simplified this a bit, by not passing around unnecessary parameters.  I've also added a log message to demonstrate how I debugged this.

You could simplify it further by doing away with the recursion.  Notice that when you call `playRound()()` at the top level, it is actually playing all of the rounds.

```js
    var moves, result;

    moves = {
        rock: 0, 
        paper: 1, 
        scissors: 2,
    };

    result = {
        win: 0,
        tie: 0,
        lose: 0
    };

    function convertMoves() {
        playerSelection = prompt('Please choose rock, paper, or scissors').toLowerCase();
        return moves[playerSelection];
    }

    function computerPlay() {
        var movesValues = Object.values(moves);
        var r = Math.random()
        var random = Math.floor(r * movesValues.length);
        //console.log(r,movesValues.length,random)
        return movesValues[random];
    } 

    function playRound() {

        // call the *choice* functions
        var c = computerPlay()
        var p = convertMoves()
        console.log(c,p) // *** debugging ***

        var processResult = (3 + c - p) % 3;

        if (!processResult) {
            ++result.tie;
            console.log('tie');
        } else if (1 == processResult) {
            ++result.lose;
            console.log('You lost');
        } else {
            ++result.win;
            console.log('You won');
        }

        return function() {
            var rounds = 0;
            var resultValues = Object.values(result);

            for (var i = 0; i < resultValues.length; i++) {
                rounds += resultValues[i];
            }

            console.log("rounds:",rounds)
            if (rounds !== 5) {
                playRound()(); // *** recursion ***
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    console.log(playRound()());
```